# Can I use ruby to edit an XML file in place, like with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I know how to parse through an XML document with Nokogiri. I have one element in which I want to re-sort the text strings, so I was thinking of either editing in-place or just writing a whole new file. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example, you'll have to modify this to work with your XML, of course.

Given your XML is something like:

```
<top>
  <node1>
    <value>mmm</value>
    <value>zzz</value>
    <value>ccc</value>
  </node1>
  <anothernode>
    <value>zzz</value>
    <value>ccc</value>
  </anothernode>
</top>
```

And if you wanted to make the children of node1 be in alphabetical order by value, you could do:

```
n = Nokogiri::XML(the_xml_i_wrote_above)
node1 = n.xpath("//node1").first
sorted_children = node1.children.sort{|x,y| x.text <=> y.text }
node1.children.each {|x| x.unlink }
sorted_children.each {|x| node1 << x}
```

And then n.to_s should be equal to:

```
<top>
  <node1>
    <value>ccc</value>
    <value>mmm</value>
    <value>zzz</value>
  </node1>
  <anothernode>
    <value>zzz</value>
    <value>ccc</value>
  </anothernode>
</top>
```

There might be more efficient ways to do this, in particular I was looking for a documented way to unlink all children at once (maybe node1.children = [] ?) or a Nokogiri way to sort the nodes. Take a look at the [Nokogiri docs](http://nokogiri.org/) for other ways to do this.

Comment: Note that you do not need to unlink the nodes before moving them. A node can only be in one spot in the tree, so appending them to an element automatically removes them from the old spot. I've put up [a short rewrite](https://gist.github.com/745244) of your code showing several minor improvements.